# R summarize problems - totals have values like '2e+04' rather than a simple count

Tags: r

I have a table with several hundred rows like below

| Area | Numerator | Denominator | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AreaA | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| AreaB | 3 | 10 | 2 |

There are 5 groups numbered 1 to 5. I am looking to create a summary table that just sums numerator and denominator by Group. Code I am using is

```
#Create table of totals by group
SummaryICS2 <- ExampleBook %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(across(-Area, sum)) %>%
  adorn_totals()
```

Instead I am getting below. Can anyone explain problem and correct code please?

[image]

Comment: Well... what should it sum up to? Have you checked manually one case? Are the numerator/denominator columns numerical?

Comment: Run `options(scipen = 99)` in the console and run the same code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
options(scipen=999)
```

Changes from scientific notation to what I was looking for.